# Metrolog on Raspberry Pi

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-iot-core, metrolog

I'm using Windows 10 IOT on my Raspberry Pi 3.

Since my Application is growing I'd like to include a logger to the application. So I've implemented [MetroLog](https://github.com/onovotny/MetroLog) for this purpose.

Starting the application on my local computer the logging works fine and it stores the lof files under this path

```
C:\Users\[login]\AppData\Local\Packages\[package family name]\LocalState\MetroLogs
```

If I start the application on the Raspberry Pi the logger does not write any log files or I just can't find it. The folder described above does not exist on the Raspberry Pi.

Has anyone implemented MetroLog for Win10 IOT apps? 
Or can I change the default path where the log files are stored?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On windows iot core device the path looks like this:

```
C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\Packages\[package family name]\LocalState\MetroLogs
```

I test with the following code piece:

```
        this.Log = Logger.GetLogger("myLogger");
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Error log files are written to: " + ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path);
        this.Log.Debug("This is a debug message.");
```